# PHP Facebook SDK - syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')'

Tags: php

Here is my code:

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
'app_id'                => '1111111', // api key
'app_secret'            => '22222222', // secret api key
'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5'
]);
```

And finally I always get this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in...

Where is a problem?

Comment: try removing `\Facebook`

Comment: It still get the same error.

Comment: Your php version is too old for the shortened array notation. Try this instead: `$fb = new Facebook\Facebook(array(...));`

Comment: I changed it and finally I got: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'The Facebook SDK requires PHP version 5.4 or higher.' in (...). So which Facebook SDK I should use to work with this script ??

Comment: Very clear error u r using older version of Php becuase yur Facebook SDK requires Php 5.4

Comment: R u working on local environment? Localhost?  If yes install the latest version

Comment: You should update your php version instead of ooking for an outdated SDK version.

Comment: @arkascha nice suggestion friend. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook(array(
'app_id'                => '1111111', // api key
'app_secret'            => '22222222', // secret api key
'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5'
));
```

Thank you,
Tom

Comment: OK, that "works" but then I got this: "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'The Facebook SDK requires PHP version 5.4 or higher.' in (...)". So which Facebook SDK version I should use to work with this script ??

Comment: I  use version 3.2. That's year 2013; it works,though. Please look at the SDK versions available **and** the required PHP version to use that particular SDK.

Comment: In case anyone has been doing too much javascript, like me, he switched the `[ ]` to `array( )`